# A simple query regarding the difference between two parameters in the function clause

Tags: swift

so just a quick question, what is the difference between

```
Int...
```

and

```
[Int]
```

in the function parameters?

For example

```
func sumOf(numbers: Int...)
```

and

```
func calculateStatistics(scores: [Int])
```

I think I understand `[Int]` which is asking for an array of Ints. But what does `Int...` mean in regards to a function parameter?

Thanks Guys.

Comment: I believe it just ease of calling the methods like `sumOf(1, 2, 3, 4)` and the other method is `calculateStatistics([1, 2, 3, 4])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the variadic parameter section [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html).

> A variadic parameter accepts zero or more values of a specified type.
>   You use a variadic parameter to specify that the parameter can be
>   passed a varying number of input values when the function is called.
>   Write variadic parameters by inserting three period characters (...)
>   after the parameter’s type name.